# Freenas Bridging networks

Tags: routing, bridge, freenas

Apologies if this has been asked before:

I have 2 networks,

```
msk1 = 192.168.0.0/24 (DHCP)
msk0 = 172.10.30.0/24 (STATIC)
```

Each picked up the correct IP Address:

```
msk0
172.10.30.5/24
msk1
192.168.0.9/24
```

However only one entry in Default Route is listed:

```
Default Routes
router
192.168.0.1
```

The issue is that this is allowing bridging, and intercepting dhcp calls.

This is how my test is configured:

```
PC--SW1--R1---R2--Inet
----|---------|
----|--|-SW2--/
----FNAS
```

Ping || trace from PC SW2 works direct, 1 hop

```
PC--SW1--R1---R2--Inet
--------------|
-------|-SW2--/
----FNAS
```

This however, works as expected, and pings via R2.

So Freenas seems to be doing bridging without being asked.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been an issue with Fnas 11.2.6, Fixed by upgrading to 11.2.7